# Call AJAX in Angular function

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, http

I have 2 problems with $http in function in this code.

```
$scope.buttonClick = function(){
    // Send input data
        $.post('lib/add_contact.php', $scope.contact, function(data){
            data = angular.fromJson(data);
            if(!data.error){
                $scope.contact = "";
                console.log('success');
            }else{
                console.log('error');
            }
        });

    // Next Code
    console.log('Next Code');
}
```

First problem is, when I want to clear a contact, it dont work immediately but only after I press key into input.
If I put

```
$scope.contact = "";
```

outside of POST, It works well.

Second problem is, why is POST called last? Output of code is

```
Code Next
success
```

but i would like that output be

```
success
Code Next
```

Thanks for ideas and answers.

Comment: AJAX is asynchronous, so its called first, continues to run in the background then console.log then some time later ajax call completes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using jQuery for the ajax call which is happening outside the angular world.  You need to trigger a digest cycle for the scope to update so the change is reflected in your view.

To fix the issue:

```
$scope.buttonClick = function(){
    // Send input data
        $.post('lib/add_contact.php', $scope.contact, function(data){
            data = angular.fromJson(data);
            if(!data.error){
                $scope.$apply(function(){ //<-- calling $apply()
                    $scope.contact = "";
                });
                console.log('success');
            }else{
                console.log('error');
            }
        });

    // Next Code
    console.log('Next Code');
}
```

However the preferred approach would to use the built in `$http` service included inside of angular which knows about angular and triggers the digest automatically.

Using `$http` (don't forget to add as a dependency to your controller)

```
$scope.buttonClick = function() {
    $http.post('lib/add_contact.php', $scope.contact).success(function(data) {
        data = angular.fromJson(data);
        if (!data.error) {
            $scope.$apply(function() { //<-- calling $apply()
                $scope.contact = "";
            });
            console.log('success');
        } else {
            console.log('error');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, first solution works well. I tried to use $http but I have problem get data in PHP so I use jQuery soluton.